# Unit Testing BI category of applications

Tags: unit-testing, ssrs-2008, ssas, etl, business-intelligence

Is there a framework to unit test applications categorized under Business Intelligence - especially on the microsoft platform? I am particularly looking at ETL, SSRS and SSAS based apps. I have heard people doing it the manual way by writing scripts. I thought of getting inputs on any frameworks or tools or practices that can reduce the manual effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the URL: http://rsunit.codeplex.com. Certainly it lacks documentation now. This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Nbi](http://Nbi.codeplex.com). This framework let you check the structure and members of your cubes but also compare query, mdx or sql, results to predefined or dynamic results. The documentation is relatively exhaustive for an open-source project